# Is it possible to write a VSTO addin for Publisher 2010 and Access 2010?

Tags: vsto, publisher

I have written a couple of VSTO addins for Word 2010 and Excel 2010. I want to be able to do the same for Publisher and Access, but there aren't project templates in Visual Studio 2010 for those. I have tried Google and failed to find anything relevant. 
Is it possible?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no rich object model for publisher or access, but just to add ribbon below link can be helpful

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/02/19/vsto-add-ins-for-access.aspx